# Delete test data after the tests run

Tags: karate

I am using Karate with SpringBoot(not using Junit runner).
I see there is callSingle() method to have a feature executed once before the tests run. Is there any function I can use to run a specific feature file after all tests are executed?

my intention is to extract "id" from API responses and save in csv file, for example, and then at the end of the execution, delete data from database using those ids.

Thank You